# How can I use WebSQL in Sencha Touch with Unique Id

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, local-storage, store, web-sql

this is my model:

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.Category', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

config: {
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'slug',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'title',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'post_count',
            type:'int'
        }
    ],
}});
```

and this is my store:

```
Ext.define('myApp.store.LocalCate',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.proxy.Sql'
],

config: {
    autoLoad:false,
    model:'myApp.model.Category',
    storeId:'LocalCate',
    proxy:{
        type: 'sql',
        database: 'myApp',
        table: 'Category'
    },
}
});
```

now the problem is that :
when i use `store.add({id:123,slug:'123',title:'123',post_count:123});`
or `store.add(Ext.create('myApp.model.Category'{id:123,slug:'123',title:'123',post_count:123});`
they both doesn't work out;
It appears that when i delete the 'id:123' and only add the data

```
{slug:'123',title:'123',post_count:123}
```

it works out and when i do `store.sync()`, the WebSql DataBase show the data without 'id'.
I do know that if i change the id to something else just like 'cate_id',it will work.
However, I want this 'id' as the idproperty, and I don't want to change it's name.
What should i do? How do you use the websql in sencha touch? I find the same problem in LocalStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer it by myself.
the model will do this when created

```
    // If it does not have an id in the data at this point, we use the one generated by the id strategy.
    // This means that we will treat this record as a phantom record from now on
    id = me.data[idProperty];
    if(!id && id !==0){
        me.data[idProperty]= me.internalId = me.id;
        me.phantom =true;
```

and if i created a model with id, it's phantom is false that tell the sencha it has it data in database so that when i sync(),it won't be pushed to the database.

only if i created the model with phantom = true can i sync() it to the database.

here is the code for addrecords:

```
    getNewRecords:function(){
    returnthis.data.filterBy(function(item){
        // only want phantom records that are valid
        return item.phantom ===true&& item.isValid();
    }).items;
},
```